# Access mutable property of immutable broadcast variable

Tags: apache-spark

I'm making Spark App but get stuck on broadcast variable. According to document, broadcast variable should be 'read only'. What if it's properties are mutable?

In local, it works like variable. I don't have cluster environment, so ...

```scala
case object Var {
   private var a = 1
   def get() = {
       a = a + 1
       a
   }
}

val b = sc.broadcast(Var)

// usage 
b.value.get   // => 2
b.value.get   // => 3
// ...
```

Is this wrong usage of broadcast? It seems destroy the broadcast variable's consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadcasts are moved from the driver JVM to executor JVMs once per executor. What happens is `Var` would get serialized on driver with its current `a`, then copied and deserialized to all executor JVMs. Let's say `get` was never called on driver before broadcasting. Now all executors get a copy of `Var` with `a = 1` and whenever they call `get`, the value of `a` in **their local JVM** gets increased by one. That's it, nothing else happens and the changes of `a` won't get propagated to any other executor or the driver and the copies of `Var` will be out of sync.

> Is this wrong usage of broadcast?

Well, the interesting question is why would you do that as only the initial value of `a` gets transferred. If the aim is to build **local** counters with a common initial value it technically works but there are much cleaner ways to implement that. If the aim is to get the value changes back to the driver then yes, it is wrong usage and [accumulators](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/rdd-programming-guide.html#accumulators) should be used instead.

> It seems destroy the broadcast variable's consistency.

Yep, definitely as explained earlier.

Comment: Thanks! Very nice answer! I need to create a broadcast variable for query, but need to update each 24 hours by network. I think this method may help.